# The camera speed is set to zero, but is still too fast. How can I lower it even more?

Tags: pc, sword-art-online-fatal-bullet

I have lowered the camera speed to the zero, and I still feel it too fast/sensitive.

How can I lower the camera speed even more?

[image]